# foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Person_Categories` (
  `PrsCatID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `PrsCategory` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`PrsCatID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Persons` (
  `PersonID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `FirstName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `OrderName` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `Email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Telephone` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `Mobile` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `StreetAddress` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `RegionID` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `PostCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `CountryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TitleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CIC_MailingList` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `FoundationMember` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `PersonCmts` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`PersonID`),
  KEY `TitleID` (`TitleID`),
  KEY `RegionID` (`RegionID`),
  KEY `CountryID` (`CountryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Persons_PersonCategories` (
  `PersonID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PrsCatID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`PersonID`,`PrsCatID`),
  KEY `PrsCatID` (`PrsCatID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 Constraints for the tables
--
ALTER TABLE `Persons`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Persons_ibfk_12` FOREIGN KEY (`TitleID`) REFERENCES `Job_Titles` (`TitleID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Persons_ibfk_14` FOREIGN KEY (`CountryID`) REFERENCES `Countries` (`CountryID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Persons_ibfk_15` FOREIGN KEY (`RegionID`) REFERENCES `Regions` (`RegionID`);

ALTER TABLE `Persons_PersonCategories`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Persons_PersonCategories_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`PrsCatID`) REFERENCES `Person_Categories` (`PrsCatID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Persons_PersonCategories_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`PersonID`) REFERENCES `Persons` (`PersonID`);
```

Persons_PersonCateogires is a linking table for a n:m relationship. When I try to insert PersonID and PrsCatID into the Persons_PersonCategories via my php application I get the following error:

> An error occurs during insert:
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`ubarry09_andrew/Persons_PersonCategories`, CONSTRAINT
>   `Persons_PersonCategories_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`PersonID`) REFERENCES
>   `Persons` (`PersonID`))

Here is the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Persons_PersonCategories
VALUES (PersonID, PrsCatID)
```

Persons and Persons_Categories tables are populated with data.

Many thanks, zan

Comment: Without seeing what you are actually trying to do that is failing (ie. the actual inserts) we can't help you.

Comment: does the persons table contain the personid you're trying to insert into persons_personcategories?

Comment: Please show 1) Your actual insert statement.  2) select count(*) from each table.  Thanks.

Comment: @StevieG, Yes, Persons contains PersonID that I'm trying to insert into Persons_PersonCategories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following SQL statement is legal, but it probably doesn't do what you intend:

```
INSERT INTO Persons_PersonCategories
VALUES (PersonID, PrsCatID);
```

This basically tries to insert `(NULL, NULL)` because it evaluates the expressions in the `VALUES` clause before it creates the row.  But the expressions name columns within the context of the yet-to-be-created row, so there are no values to use.  Thus it uses NULL for both.

NULLs are not allowed in PRIMARY KEY columns, and MySQL automatically promotes NULL values when you use them for primary key columns.  In this case it promotes them to the integer value 0.  There is no value 0 in the Persons and PersonCategories tables, so you get an FK error.

Try this experiment:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Persons_PersonCategories2` (
  `PersonID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PrsCatID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`PersonID`,`PrsCatID`),
  KEY `PrsCatID` (`PrsCatID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

That is, a table like the one you created, but with no FK constraints.

```
INSERT INTO Persons_PersonCategories2
VALUES (PersonID, PrsCatID);

SELECT * FROM Persons_PersonCategories2;
+----------+----------+
| PersonID | PrsCatID |
+----------+----------+
|        0 |        0 |
+----------+----------+
```

---

You get foreign key constraint errors when you try to insert a value in an FK column that doesn't exist in the referenced PK column of the parent.  Zero is typically not used by auto-increment primary keys, so it's bound to fail.

What you need to do is provide this INSERT with the primary values from the respective  tables you want to reference.  Like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Persons_PersonCategories (PersonID, PrsCatID) 
    VALUES (?, ?)");
```

Using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) is easy and it helps to protect against SQL injection mistakes.  Then supply values from the other tables when you execute.  These values are automatically bound to the `?` placeholders you used in the prepared query:

```
$stmt->execute( array(1234, 5678) );
```

As long as those values 1234 and 5678 correspond to existing rows in your referenced tables Persons and PersonCategories, the foreign key constraint will be satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for this Bill. It's worked. My question: From a db design point of view, do I need FK constrains in linking tables at all? I was taught they are necessary for data integrity

Comment: I do use FK constraints.  IMHO, without them, your data is practically guaranteed to accumulate orphans.

Comment: Is there any way I could implement FK constraints without getting the 'FK constraint fails error'? Can you recommend a reading if possible?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a FOREIGN KEY constraint set on the Persons_PersonCategories table that is not allowing you to add any PersonID to the Persons_PersonCategories table that doesn't already exist in the Persons table.  You also have another FOREIGN KEY on your Persons_PersonCategories table that only allows you to add a PrsCatID that already exists in the Person_Categories table.  It seems as though you are trying to add a PersonID to the Persons_Categories table that does not exist in the Persons table.

Make sure the PersonID you are adding to the Persons_PersonCategories table exists in the Persons table before you try to add the record to the Persons_PersonCategories table.  The same thing goes for adding a PrsCatID to this table; first make sure the PrsCatID exists in the Person_Category table.  If you don't want the Persons_PersonCategories table to prevent you from inserting values that don't already exist in the Persons and Person_Category tables, then you will have to remove the FOREIGN KEYS (or CONSTRAINTs as they are shown in your code example).  To remove the CONSTRAINTs use the following line:

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] DROP FOREIGN KEY [CONSTRAINT_NAME]
```

Comment: The question is certainly a bit "ambiguous" as to what it is asking, but anyhows I don't think this is an answer.

Comment: @Chris, I'm not trying to insert PersonID into Person_Categories. I'm trying to insert PersonID and PrsCatID into Persons_PersonCategories which is a linking table for n:m relationship between Persons and Person_Categories

Comment: Zan, I understand what you are trying to do, I have a typo in my response.  Anywhere that I typed "Persons_Categories" I should have typed "Persons_PersonCategories".  I will update it now.

Comment: Thanks Chris, The PersonID I'm trying to insert into Persons_PersonCategories exists. I thought the problem was with NULL values, but this isn't the case either.

Comment: Just to test things out, why don't you create another table with no constraints and run your inserts on it.  Then, you can check the values in the new table against the Persons and Person_Categories table to confirm that the values exist in them.